# Windows Phone 8 Callback WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, callback, wcf-callbacks

I have a Windows Phone 8 Application and a WCF Service that implements Callback model. I'm having trouble configuring the service reference. I've tested the service using wsDualHttpBinding for a Windows Form Application Client instead the WP8 App, and it worked perfectly. However, this binding is not suitable for WP8 Apps and I have to change configuration. Can someone suggest me a simple working configuration for the service that works with my WP8 Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explain here:
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/05/03/understanding-microsoft-push-notifications-for-windows-phones.aspx

the problem is due to the fact that it is not possible to implement something like a callback or publish/subscribe model between WP8 App and a Service. This is to avoid energy loss of the phone.
So, Microsoft permits notifications from Service using the Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS). All is well-explained in the documentation linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on **References** and Select **Add Service Reference**

[image]

Type your WCF address

[image]

Click OK and you should see the Added Web Service

[image]

The Visual Studio will automatically implements the WCF service. Then you can use it

```
MyWebService.Service1Client client = new MyWebService.Service1Client();
```

I don't know if this can help you.

Comment: Hi Alen, thank you for the answer. This is what I've done to create the Service Reference, but then in the code it was not accessible. Now, I know this problem was that I cannot implement callback model in WP8 App: I have to use Push Notifications. For more details, please see the documentation linked in my answer.